# TeamCity error MSB3021: Unable to copy file

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have a TeamCity. I have setup build for my web project (csproj) with msbuild,
command line parameter is looks like

> /p:Configuration=%env.Configuration%  /p:outputpath=bin2
>   /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:IsDesktopBuild=false
>   /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
>   /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=*httppath*
>   /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
>   /p:UserName=xxx /p:Password=xxx

but build faild all the time with error:

```
Step 1/1: MSBuild (7s)
pathxxx\MyPortal.csproj.teamcity: Build target: Build (4s)
[pathxxx\MyPortal.csproj.teamcity] _CopyWebApplicationLegacy
[_CopyWebApplicationLegacy] Copy
[Copy] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(178, 5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "Bin\MyPortal.dll" to "bin2\_PublishedWebsites\MyPortal.csproj\Bin\MyPortal.dll". Could not find a part of the path 'Bin\MyPortal.dll'.
[Copy] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(178, 5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "Bin\MyPortal.pdb" to "bin2\_PublishedWebsites\MyPortal.csproj\Bin\MyPortal.pdb". Could not find a part of the path 'Bin\MyPortal.pdb'.
[pathxxx\MyPortal.csproj.teamcity] Project pathxxx\MyPortal.csproj.teamcity failed.
[Step 1/1] Step MSBuild failed
```

if I removed /p:outputpath=bin2 parameter i see other king of error,

> The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'MyPortal.csproj.teamcity'.  Please check to
>   make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration
>   and Platform for this project.  Configuration='TestEnv'  Platform='Any
>   CPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build
>   a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default
>   Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

I am using xml transformation and I have make shure that TestEnv is exist in all project inside solution.

What it could be ? and how to fix it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you added a configuration testenv to all your projects? as its missing the **OutputPath** property.Alternatively you could just add the property to your initial command e.g. `/p:OutputPath=..\output` .